# Chip identification

Tags: atmel

Can someone help me identify this chip. I think it is an Atmel EEPROM but which model?

[image]

Comment: I also found some information about sale of this chip on google, but couldn't find a datasheet. Maybe you can chat or email with one of the saleman to ask?

Answer (score 2):

It should be an Atmel I2C EEPROM. AT24CS04. 4KBit

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-8766-seeprom-at24cs04-08-datasheet.pdf

See page 15 for Part Markings.8-lead SOIC.

2 - Is year 2012

38 - Is week

N4 - 4 KBit version

M - Month (?)

Y - Country (?)

2W3385A - Lot Number